# websocket: packet seen in wireshark, but on_message callback is not called in webSocketApp

Tags: python, websocket

Below is the python code I have for a websocket using WebSocketApp. I'm sending a message and trying to read the response. While I see some response is sent by the server, in wireshark, none of the callbacks are getting executed.

```
def on_data(a,b,c,d):
    print ("on_data:", a, b, c, d)
def on_message(wsapp, message):
    print("received message:", message)
def on_ping(wsapp, message):
    print("Got a ping! A pong reply has already been automatically sent.")
def on_pong(wsapp, message):
    print("Got a pong! No need to respond")
def on_close(wsapp,status,message):
    print ("closed")
def on_open(wsapp):
    print ("opened")
def on_error(wsapp, error):
    print ("error")
wsapp = websocket.WebSocketApp(link, on_close=on_close, on_open=on_open, on_message=on_message, on_ping=on_ping, on_pong=on_pong, on_data=on_data, on_error=on_error)
wsapp.run_forever(dispatcher=rel, ping_interval=60, ping_timeout=10, ping_payload=None)
while True:
    msg = input("enter message:")
    wsapp.send(msg)
```

At the same time, if I directly use websockets, as in the below code, for the same message I'm getting a response and could print and verify it.

```
ws = websocket.create_connection(link, timeout=5)
while True:
    msg = input("enter message:")
    print (ws.send(msg))
    print (ws.recv())
```

Below is the wireshark snippet
[image: wireshark snippet]

Can someone help me understand what could have I done wrongly while using WebSocketApp?

Its a duplicate of [python websocketapp on_message() method not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57657811/python-websocketapp-on-message-method-not-working?rq=2)

Answer (score 1):

Went through WebSocketApp code and realized they call dispatcher's read for reading message from the socket. In my code, I was using "rel" as the dispatcher. I will have to read about it and understand how to use it properly.

```
wsapp.run_forever(dispatcher=rel, ping_interval=60, ping_timeout=10, ping_payload=None)
```

In the meantime, I created a different thread for the websocketApp and used their default dispatcher (which is blocking), and ran the code to read message from user in the main thread, and its working as expected.
Sorry and thanks.